# Django create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined

Tags: django, python-2.7

i'm a newbie and i want ask something that may be sound basic, i've just read on Django 1.9 documentation about create a relationship on a model that has not yet been defined, it says that "you can use the name of the model, rather than the model object itself" than i try it, this is my code :

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Student(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teachers=models.ForeignKey('Teacher')

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

when i try to save a Student object it gives me errors like this :
"OperationalError: table latihan_student has no column named teachers_id"
Can someone explain it thank you verry much. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

This isn't anything to do with how you define the ForeignKey. You added a field to your table; you need to migrate the database.

Comment: yes i've just make migrations ./manage.py makemigrations [my app], ./manage.py sqlmigrate [my app] 0001, and ./manage.py migrate. Then i try again to save Student objects and it gives me an error again "IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: latihan_student.teachers_id". Iam jus curious how to make relationship for a model that has not yeet been defined.....

Comment: I think you are confused. The docs are talking about writing the models so that you can define the ForeignKey field before the model it points to. I *think* you are talking about creating a relationship with an *instance* that has not been defined, which is obviously impossible.

Comment: yes you're rigtht... i've not been make any teacher objects i thinks that makes the latest error, then i make one teacher object and also i add a keyword argument to my foreignkeyrelationship (null=True) and done i did it.... Thank you verry much

Answer (score 0):

Update your Teacher models as follows :

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Teacher(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    teachers = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

Now you can use and create it's object in other models. You got another error because after creating objects it already has entry in the database to which you haven't say null=True so you was getting integrity error, So add null=True for the field in which you are getting integrity error .